# The :name method said not to exist in collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the countries gem installed in a Rails app and wanted to create a collection select with it like this

```
  <%= f.collection_select :country, Country.all, :id, :name %>
```

but it's giving me this error (for the first country).

```
undefined method `name' for ["Andorra", "AD"]:Array.
```

If I do Country.all in the console with this gem, it creates an array of countries like this

```
Country.all

=> [["Andorra", "AD"], ["United Arab Emirates", "AE"], ["Afghanistan", "AF"], ["Antigua and Barbuda", "AG"], ["Anguilla", "AI"], ["Albania", "AL"], ["Armenia", "AM"], ["Netherlands Antilles", "AN"], ["Angola", "AO"], ["Antarctica", "AQ"], ["Argentina", "AR"], ["American Samoa", "AS"], ["Austria", "AT"], ["Australia", "AU"], ["Aruba", "AW"], ["Åland Islands", "AX"], ["Azerbaijan", "AZ"],
```

If i create an instance of a country like this passing in it's two letter code

```
>> c = Country.new('US')
```

I can then get a name method

```
>> c.name
=> "United States"
```

I'm trying to do it with the countries gem because I couldn't figure out how to create a collection select with the `countries_select` gem.  If you can't tell me how to fix the problem with the countries gem, then please let me know how to do it with the countries_select gem.

Comment: What do you want to be saved as the `country` attribute? "Andorra"? "AD"? Something else?

Comment: I've wrote about country_select gem

Comment: @bgates the full name of the country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install gem 'country_select' to provide helper that renders select tag.
You pass model and attribute names and it renders select box. If you have User model and country attribute in it write

```
<%= country_select(:user, :country) %>
```

and it will produce

```
<select id="user_country" name="user[country]"><option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
....
</select>
```

https://github.com/hexorx/countries

https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select